# C++ code buggy, needs fixing

Tags: c++, validation, input

Hey guys I've got this piece of code, posted below. I've added the while loop to make sure that only numeric input is used, but when I use it, it requires me to input the number twice, or press enter and then input the number.

Output would be:

```
Input number : 1
1
```

then it would it would print the results. How can I fix this Cheers.

```
 void Dictionary::SearchNumeric()
{
    int x;
    cout << "Input number : ";
    while (!(cin >> x))
    {
        cout << "Invalid input.  Try again: ";
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max());

    }
    string searchWord = myWords[x]->word;
    cout << "Word searched: " << searchWord << endl;
    cout << "Definition: \n" << myWords[x]->definition << endl;
    cout << "Type: " << myWords[x]->type << endl;
    int wordIndex = 0;
    //while (myWords[wordIndex]->word.compare(x) != 0) {
    //needs to return scrabble score
    wordIndex++;
    //break;
    //}

}
```

Comment: You call `cin >> x` at least twice in a row - why exactly are you surprised that you have to enter a number twice?

Comment: Why not just move `string searchWord = myWords[x]->word;` to after the while loop and remove the line `cin >> x;`?

Comment: C++ non-descriptive title, needs fixing.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To get a good response, I recommend asking a specific question about a technology or technique. It is better to ask for help on understanding a technology (like streams) than to ask for general help debugging a block of code. Please see the about page: http://stackoverflow.com/about.

Comment: Me Tarzan, You Jane. Me code buggy. You fix it.

Answer (score 5):

Get rid of the first `cin >> x;`, set the `string searchWord` after the while

Comment: +1 and maybe even check that `x` is within the boundaries of `[0...myWords.size())`

Comment: I think it will also need a `cin.clear();` in the `while` loop to get rid of the error flag.

Comment: change it to `while(cin>>x)` and break the loop when you get a numeric value, meaning test the value before writing an error.  cin should be blocking, does it only error when you press a key?

Comment: Anyway I managed to fix it, it's working fine now.